# Loading images based on JSON file react

Tags: reactjs

I have a create react app. I am making an AJAX request and I receive JSON that looks like this.

{id: "b2", title: "Huang's World", episodes: 12, product_image_url: "/images/huangsworld.jpg"}

In my create react app I  have an images folder that has all of the corresponding images, I want to load the image based on the product_url.

```
<img src={ product_image_url} <--- Doesn't work
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You need quotes around it: `<img src={"/images/huangsworld.jpg"}`

Comment: Sorry, I meant the variable product_image_url doesn't work, because the path is incorrect. Is it a problem with webpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set url in state since when you get json from your ajax request your component will not re-render since img is just an html tag and will not update so you need to make sure it re-render by setting url in state,so when there is change is in state it will re-render.
You can do something like this.
// on success of ajax request

```
this.setState({url: product_image_url})
```

and then in render use like this.

```
<img src={this.state.url}/>
```